# Run javascript code each time a page is opened

Tags: javascript, browser

I often find myself using this line of code on the console of the browser:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].playbackRate = 1.5;
```

I use it so I can speed up a video (I just prefer to watch videos on a higher speed). Is there a way to make this line of code run on every web page I open. For example if I go to a youtube video, this line of code runs automatically. I know that YouTube already has buttons for speed, but some players don't have the UI for this and this is why I have to do this often. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Write a browser extension.

Comment: There is a browser extension I haven't tired it yet.

<https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en>

Comment: You can install the GreaseMonkey (Firefox) or TamperMonkey (Chrome) extensions and add that as a userscript.

Comment: You can try writing userscript.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote a simple userscript and it worked perfectly :)